# How to assign a value to to a field stored in a custom setting?

Tags: trigger, appexchange, customsetting

I'm building an app and I'm giving users the ability to select a specific field to populate from a list of all of their fields. I'm storing that field's API name in a custom setting.

I want to create a trigger that assigns a value to that field.

It tried concatenating 'c.' + the field API name, but I get an "Expression cannot be assigned" error.

```
Settings__c settings = Settings__c.getOrgDefaults();

for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {

    'c.' + settings.Field__c = 'test'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a string that holds a field name, you need to use SObject's `.put()` and `.get()` instead of the normal dot-notation.

`c.put(settings.Field__c, 'test');`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Derek. Unfortunately, I now a get a different error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void set(String, String) from the type Contact

Comment: @JohnvanZalk My bad, the method is actually `.put()`. Answer updated.

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JohnvanZalk If your issue has been resolved, then it's part of the stackexchange culture to upvote (once you get 15 reputation score) and accept the answer that you found most helpful or most correct. Doing that is optional, but it does a few things. It gives you and the answerer reputation (+2 for you, +15 for the answerer), signals to the community that the question doesn't need more attention, and helps other people coming from google with similar issues find things that will probably work for them too.

Comment: Yep, I understand. I tried upvoting, but realized I needed that score. Just accepted! Thanks again.